# how to deal with missing value in if else statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe, [mydata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vHOh.png), constructed as follows:

```
col1<-c(8.20e+07, 1.75e+08, NA, 4.80e+07, 
       3.40e+07, NA, 5.60e+07, 3.00e+06 )
col2<-c(1960,1960,1965,1986,1960
        ,1969,1960,1993)
col3<-c ( NA,2.190,NA,NA, 5.000, NA,
          1.700,4.220)
mydata<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)

mydata

#       col1 col2 col3
# 1 8.20e+07 1960   NA
# 2 1.75e+08 1960 2.19
# 3       NA 1965   NA
# 4 4.80e+07 1986   NA
# 5 3.40e+07 1960 5.00
# 6       NA 1969   NA
# 7 5.60e+07 1960 1.70
# 8 3.00e+06 1993 4.22
```

I want to create a `col4` that has the values `"a", "b" and "c"`,
if `col1` is smaller than 4.00e+07, then `col4=="a"`; if `col1` is not less than 4.00e+07, then `col4=="b"`, else `col4=="c`"

Here is my code:

```
col4 <-ifelse(col1<4.00e+07, "a",                  
       ifelse(col1 >=4.00e+07, "b",                         
       ifelse(is.na(col1 =4.00e+07), "b",  "c" )))
```

but this evaluates to:

```
# [1] "b" "b" NA  "b" "a" NA  "b" "a"
```

It doesn't change the NA value in col1 as "c".

The outcome should be:

```
 #  [1] "b" "b" "c"  "b" "a" "c" "b" "a"
```

What is the problem in my code? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to check `is.na` first, because `NA < 4.00e+07` results in `NA`. If the first argument of `ifelse()` is `NA`, the result will be `NA` as well:

```
ifelse(c(NA, TRUE, FALSE), "T", "F")
## [1] NA  "T" "F"
```

As you can see, for the first vector element the result is indeed `NA`. Even if the other arguments of `ifelse()` have special code that would take care of this situation, it won't help because that code is never taken into account.

For your example, checking for `NA` first gives you the desired result:

```
col4 <- ifelse(is.na(col1), "c",
               ifelse(col1 < 4.00e+07, "a","b"))
col4
## [1] "b" "b" "c" "b" "a" "c" "b" "a"
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be also done with `cut`

```
v1 <- with(mydata, as.character(cut(col1, 
    breaks=c(-Inf, 4.00e+07, Inf), labels=c("a", "b"))))
v1[is.na(v1)] <- "c"
v1
#[1] "b" "b" "c" "b" "a" "c" "b" "a"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. one more question is that does `breaks=c(-Inf, 4.00e+07, Inf), labels=c("a", "b")` mean that `[4.00e+07, Inf)` will give a label of `"b"`?

Comment: @eclo.qh Yes, you are right.  You can check it with `with(mydata, cut(col1, breaks=c(-Inf, 4.00e+07, Inf)))`

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun.

Comment: @eclo.qh  No problem.  Glad to help you.